# Clicker Counter Deduction

Tags: c#

i'm very new to coding and i'm trying to make a simple click counter for a 'item logger' for my game i play, i'm kind of at a stand still now...

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int Count = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Count++;
            label1.Text = Count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my attempt at making a right click deduct which doesn't work for me at all...

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int Count = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Count++;
                label1.Text = Count.ToString();
            }
            else if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                Count--;
                label1.Text = Count.ToString();            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, please don't use too technical terms as i'm am still learning and just need that little bump of help. thanks!

Comment: What about it doesn't work?  What happens when you run that code?

Comment: the code launches and when i click it starts to count up, but when i right click nothing happens when i want it to deduct

Comment: Do you know how to debug, I would suggest setting a break point and checking to see if the event is triggered as expected

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it >.< i'm stupid i was using the wrong event i needed to use mousedown instead of mouseclick. sorry to waste time!